# Android: SimpleDateFormat keeps adding 1 hour to my time

Tags: android, time, simpledateformat

I'm using `currentTimeMillis();` to get a start time, then later using it again to get an end time. I then use delete start from end and get a value which is the duration between the two. I am using `SimpleDateFormat` to make all these values pretty and readable. the only thing is when i'm using a low value like 10 seconds (or 300 etc) and not the full blown long number (i.e. 1335718053126)  I appear be getting out 01:00:10 or 01:02:12 etc on all my outputs?  in fact if I just ask SimpleDateFormat to output a hh:mm:ss value against a 0 value it reads 01:00:00.

any one know why this is?

Found this neat little code if anyone else needs a solution to time formatting.
[Source link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378404/java/java/Convert-milliseconds-time)

```
public String getNiceTime(long time) {     

    String format = String.format("%%0%dd", 2);
    String seconds = String.format(format, time % 60);
    String minutes = String.format(format, (time % 3600) / 60);
    String hours = String.format(format, time / 3600);
    String outPutTime =  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return outPutTime;
}
```

Comment: You are using dates, and not a time format. Could have something to do with summer time maybe?

Comment: I think you are right, do you know how I can alter the timezone of this or is there a simpletimeformat I can use?

Comment: I don't know of a good way to output just time, you might need to calculate the hours:min:sec yourself.

Comment: I have managed to set it to UTC but now its set to 12 not 1, doh this is starting to look like a manual conversion. I really want to avoid that..

Comment: I just saw your update. yes I think I'll have to, shame though. was really starting to like this simpledateformat thing.

Comment: right, I've found some neat code. If you want to write your comment up as an answer I'll tick it off.

Comment: You can "up vote" my comment if you like it, don't need a good answer check from my guess :)

Answer (score 2):

```
mySimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Explanation: you are probably living in a GMT+1 time zone and unless you specify a different one, your formatter will pick your current one, so it considers 0 hours as GMT and as you are in GMT+1, it outputs 1 hour